# Unable to add www prefix to my website

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to add `www` prefix to my domain. My domain is `developigner.com`.

I have used this code in .htaccess file but still am not able to get the desired result.

Here's my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^developigner.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.developigner.com/$1 [R=301,nc,L]
```

The problem is that if I type `developigner.com` it gets redirected to `www.your_domain.com` and if I type `www.developigner.com` it works perfectly.

I want `your_domain` to be replaced by `developigner`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The fact that it gets redirected to `your_domain`, and I don't see that in your `.htaccess`, hints that there is another rule somewhere that's overriding the above.

Comment: When I opened `developigner.com` it became `www.developigner.com`. Use a new browser to test.

Comment: so how do i get rid of that ?

Comment: @user3514160: Try searching for any files containing the text `your_domain`.

Comment: @anubhava you are right. I am using firefox and when am doing it, it gets redirected to `www.your_domain.com`, when tried in chrome, it works prefectly.

Comment: @user3514160 Clear your cache on firefox.  It could be some old data rumbling around that's screwing things up

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as expected: developigner.com redirects to www.developigner.com.

I notice you only registered the domain yesterday. It's possible this problem is actually caused by delays in the global propagation of your domain name.